# Pass array to graphQL query using axios

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, foreach, graphql

I have a graphQL mutation that I am running using axios inside of a `forEach` loop. One of the values I am passing is an array but when I run my function, the function just gets stuck there and does not execute nor does it error out. How do I pass an array of strings to a graphQL mutation?

My code:

```
const createMut = (id, res) => `
    mutation {
        createField(input: {
            id: "${id}",
            label: "${res.label}",
            options: ${res.options}
            }) {
            table_field {
              id
              label
            }
        }
    }
`;

const myFunc = (id, result) => {
    result.data.forEach(d => {
        axiosFunc({ query: create_fields(id, d) }).then((response) => response);
    });
}
```

`d.options` inside of result is set in `['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3']` format. But when I call my function. My code is just getting stuck and not adding that field. How do I send an array to a graphQL mutation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do pass as a JSON string in **options** property

Like this below code :-

```
options: JSON.stringify(res.options)
```

and need to update your **myFunc**

Like this below code :-

```js
const myFunc = (id, result) => {

  result.data.forEach(d => {

    const mutation = createMut(id, d);

    axios.post('/graphql', { query: mutation }).then((response) => response);

  });
}
```